# How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run an application.I am getting error :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.SquareImageView"

But I have already created SquareImageView class inside the java folder in android. Still I am getting this error.

Part of the  error :

```
> 2022-02-22 20:29:08.081 1987-1987/com.beproject.sharepixel
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>             Process: com.beproject.sharepixel, PID: 1987
>             android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class SquareImageView
>             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class SquareImageView
>             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.SquareImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.beproject.sharepixel-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.beproject.sharepixel-1/lib/x86,
> /data/app/com.beproject.sharepixel-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib,
> /vendor/lib]]
>                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:700)
>                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>                 at com.beproject.sharepixel.StoryListAdapter.getView(StoryListAdapter.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view XML file you are using `SquareImageView` as the class reference without the full package name. Because you don't include the full package name, Anroid assumes that `SquareImageView` is in the `android.view` package and cannot find the class. You need to add the full package name in your view XML file.